# how to download co-occurance matrix for glove pre-trained word vectors

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, glove

I am trying to train glove embeddings on a domain corpus, trying to experiment with incremental training with existing glove vectors, but unable to get the co-occurrence matrix for glove pre-trained word vectors. how do I get the **co-occurrence matrix**?